# Android: Layout breaks when Text Size changed

Tags: android, xml, layout

Following is my Android layout for 3 buttons. It looks nice and good. But when I change the button's Text size of a single button to some other value it breaks the layout (font size and gravity changed but).

Before:

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF">

        <Button android:id="@+id/allimagebtn" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/cam_red" android:text="Images" android:gravity="bottom" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2video" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/vid_red" android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Video Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
            
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3audio" android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/aud_red" android:text="Audio Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

After:

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <Button android:id="@+id/allimagebtn" android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="@drawable/cam_red" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp" android:textSize="30dp" android:text="1" android:gravity="top"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2video" android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vid_red" android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Video Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>
        
    <Button android:id="@+id/button3audio" android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:background="@drawable/aud_red" android:text="Audio Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to avoid this??

Comment: "Breaks the layout" is not the most helpful description. Could you be more specific about what you expect to see, and what you see instead? Screenshots get bonus points. Annotated screenshots get unicorns.

Comment: i changed and added more info with scren shots. can u check please :)

Comment: Much more helpful. I'd take a stab at it, but three people below have my best guesses already. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code. You have fixed the height and width of the view which is not a good idea.
I tested with wrap_content and it is working fine.So try to avoid the fixed height and width and instead use wrap_content and fill_parent which fits your need. You can use Relative Layout if you face any problem.

Comment: thanks I changed to fill_parent for height and it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are setting `layout_weight` and `layout_width`
Try this (setting `layout_weight` to `1` and `layout_width` to `0`)

If it suits you, it should work (**Even distribution of children of linearlayout**)

**Try this**

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="#FFF">

        <Button android:id="@+id/allimagebtn" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/cam_red" android:text="Images" android:gravity="bottom" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button2video" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/vid_red" android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Video Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button3audio" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:background="@drawable/aud_red" android:text="Audio Files" android:gravity="bottom" android:textSize="12dp" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingTop="2dp" android:layout_marginTop="2dp" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_margin="2dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Like @Mansi said add gravity = center ... but the problem is that you are using a percentage weight and at the same time setting the width ... Why didnt my code work !?

Answer (score 1):

I saw your code you have to add **android:gravity="center"** in your LinearLayout.

For Example,

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:weightSum="1.0" android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:background="#FFF" android:gravity="center">
     </LinearLayout>
```

I think your problem will be solved. Try it.

Thanks.